# Name error: Variable not defined

Tags: python

Program calculates the shortest route from point, to line, then to second point. Also I need to say how long is from the start of the line, to where point crosses. My code so far:

```
from math import sqrt
numbers_total = []
numbers_canal = []
first_triangle_longest_side_length = 300   #defining the variable

def first_triangle(first_triangle_longest_side_length):
    calculation_one = sqrt(first_triangle_longest_side_length)
    first_triangle_bottom_side_length = calculation_one - sqrt(300)

def second_triangle(canal_length_left):
    canal_length_left = canal_length_left ** 2
    calculation_two = canal_length_left + 500 ** 2
    second_triangle_longest_side_length = sqrt(calculation_two)


while True:
    first_triangle_longest_side_length = first_triangle_longest_side_length + 0.01
    first_triangle(first_triangle_longest_side_length)
    canal_length_left = 1000 - first_triangle_bottom_side_length
    second_triangle(canal_length_left)
    if first_triangle_longest_side_length == 1044.03:
        break
    total_distance = first_triangle_longest_side_length + second_triangle_longest_side_length
    numbers_total.append(total_distance)
    numbers_canal.append(first_trangle_bottom_side_length)

minimal_total_distance = min(numbers_total)
number_on_the_list = numbers_total.index(minimal_total_distance)
print "The distance of the shortest route is: " + "%.1f" %     minimal_total_distance
print "The distance of the canal from point A is: " + "%.1f" % numbers_canal[number_on_the_list]
```

However, it gives the error:

```
line 19, in <module>
    canal_length_left = 1000 - first_triangle_bottom_side_length
NameError: name 'first_triangle_bottom_side_length' is not defined
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Read about scopes and functions, `first_triangle_bottom_side_length` is undefined anywhere outside the `first_triangle()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking another look at your answer I realized your math is also wrong. I will point out your syntax and math errors and add a bit of free advice along the way ;-)

Stepping through your original code:

```
from math import sqrt
numbers_total = []
numbers_canal = []
first_triangle_longest_side_length = 300   #defining the variable
```

Really? `where_on_earth_did_you_learn_variable_naming`? Try `tower_dist = 300`.

```
def first_triangle(tower_hypot):
    calculation_one = sqrt(tower_hypot)
    first_triangle_bottom_side_length = calculation_one - sqrt(300)
```

First mistake: assigning a value to `first_triangle_bottom_side_length` doesn't accomplish anything. The variable is of local scope (ie it only exists inside this function) so as soon as the function ends it disappears.

You *could* be completely evil and make it a global variable, or you could just `return calculation_one - sqrt(300)` instead.

Second mistake: the math is just wrong. I'll come back to that in a moment.

```
def second_triangle(canal_length_left):
    canal_length_left = canal_length_left ** 2
    calculation_two = canal_length_left + 500 ** 2
    second_triangle_longest_side_length = sqrt(calculation_two)
```

Same error again; do `return sqrt(calculation_two)` instead.

Important note: naming conventions! `first_triangle` returns a base length, `second_triangle` returns a hypotenuse. This is more than a bit confusing. Also, both functions have constants hard-wired in, meaning the functions cannot be reused for anything else.

---

If you instead did:

```
def side(adjacent, hypotenuse):
    """
    Given the side and hypotenuse of a right triangle,
      return the other side
    """
    return (hypotenuse**2 - adjacent**2) ** 0.5

def hypotenuse(adjacent, opposite):
    """
    Given two sides of a right triangle,
      return the hypotenuse
    """
    return (adjacent**2 + opposite**2) ** 0.5

def tower_base(tower_hypot, tower_height=300):
    return side(tower_height, tower_hypot)

def fire_hypot(fire_base, fire_height=500):
    return hypotenuse(fire_base, fire_height)
```

This is general enough to be reusable, has meaningful but not ridiculously long variable names, and can easily be tested for correctness:

```
assert side(3, 5)  == 4
assert side(5, 13) == 12
assert hypotenuse(3, 4)  == 5
assert hypotenuse(5, 12) == 13

# a (300, 400, 500) triangle
assert tower_base(500) == 400

# a (500, 1200, 1300) triangle
assert fire_hypot(1200) == 1300
```

Testing your previous code:

```
# should make a (300, 400, 500) triangle
assert first_triangle(500) == 400   # 5.04017 ?!  FAIL
```

And there is the math error: `first_triangle` returns `tower_hypot**0.5 - 300**0.5` which is a meaningless quantity; it should be `(tower_hypot**2 - 300**2)**0.5`.

Unit analysis gives us a quick way to double-check; if `tower_hypot` is in meters, the first equation returns root-of-meters (which makes no sense) while the second returns meters (which is what we expected). That does not necessarily make it *correct* - but it makes it *not obviously incorrect,* which is a good start!

---

```
while True:
    tower_hypot += 0.01

    first_triangle(first_triangle_longest_side_length)
```

You called the function correctly, but you didn't keep the result anywhere; try `a_dist = tower_base(tower_hypot)`.

```
    canal_length_left = 1000 - a_dist
    second_triangle(canal_length_left)
```

Again you haven't kept the function result; try `fire_dist = fire_hypot(1000 - a_dist)`.

```
    if first_triangle_longest_side_length == 1044.03:
        break
```

Magic numbers! What fun!

- it is not clear what this value means (it is `(300**2 + 1000**2)**0.5` which is the maximum possible value of `tower_hypot`, but that is unclear at first glance)
- floating point math means `==` is almost never going to work; you want `>` or `>=` instead
- you have hard-coded in values for tower_height, canal_length, fire_height - which is bad practice - but you have now also hard-coded in values *derived from* those values, making your program very difficult to maintain (what happens next week, when the ranger sees a fire 1200 meters away and 200 meters from the canal? Does he have to rewrite the program from scratch to figure out where to go?)

then

```
    total_distance = first_triangle_longest_side_length + second_triangle_longest_side_length
    numbers_total.append(total_distance)
    numbers_canal.append(first_trangle_bottom_side_length)

minimal_total_distance = min(numbers_total)
number_on_the_list = numbers_total.index(minimal_total_distance)
print "The distance of the shortest route is: " + "%.1f" %     minimal_total_distance
print "The distance of the canal from point A is: " + "%.1f" % numbers_canal[number_on_the_list]
```

---

With a few more modifications the code looks like

```
# use named variables!
# - makes it easy to modify the program later
# - makes it easier to figure out what's going on
TOWER_HEIGHT = 300
CANAL_LENGTH = 1000
FIRE_HEIGHT  = 500

# generic functions which can be reused!
def side(adjacent, hypotenuse):
    """
    Given the side and hypotenuse of a right triangle,
      return the other side
    """
    return (hypotenuse**2 - adjacent**2) ** 0.5

def hypotenuse(adjacent, opposite):
    """
    Given two sides of a right triangle,
      return the hypotenuse
    """
    return (adjacent**2 + opposite**2) ** 0.5

# work from the most obvious control value
def total_dist(a_dist):
    tower_hypot = hypotenuse(a_dist, TOWER_HEIGHT)
    b_dist      = CANAL_LENGTH - a_dist
    fire_hypot  = hypotenuse(b_dist, FIRE_HEIGHT)
    return tower_hypot + fire_hypot

def main():
    step_size = 0.1

    # equivalent of
    # a_dists = numpy.arange(0.0, CANAL_LENGTH, step_size)
    num_steps = int(CANAL_LENGTH / step_size)
    a_dists   = (k*step_size for k in range(num_steps + 1))

    # find minimum distance
    best_a_dist     = min(a_dists, key=total_dist)
    best_total_dist = total_dist(best_a_dist)

    print("The distance of the shortest route is: {:0.1f}".format(best_total_dist))
    print("The distance of the canal from point A is: {:0.1f}".format(best_a_dist))

main()
```

Comment: Thank you! It wasn't easy for me to write this program, as I'm only beginner, but I will remember your tips

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, here is the problem: [Cambridge February Computing Competition](https://www.cambridge.org/ukschools/news/february-computing-competition)

You are taking a very brute-force approach; <s>it works, but could be much more efficient</s> **Edit: I take it back; your math is incorrect too. I will correct it in a new post**.

Here is a more analytic way to do it:

```
TOWER_DIST = 300
CANAL_LEN  = 1000
FIRE_DIST  = 500

#
#  express the problem as a function
#
def path_length(dist_a):
    """
    Given distance in meters from A along the canal,
      return total path length
    """
    leg_a = (TOWER_DIST**2 + dist_a**2) ** 0.5
    leg_b = ((CANAL_LEN - dist_a)**2 + FIRE_DIST**2) ** 0.5
    return leg_a + leg_b

#
# find x such that path_length(x) is minimized
#

# (the easy way:
# import scipy.optimize
# result = scipy.optimize.minimize(path_length, CANAL_LEN * 0.5)
# best_dist   = result.x[0]              # =>  375.00092001
# best_length = path_length(best_dist)   # => 1280.6248
#
# but because this is a competition we will avoid add-on modules)

def deriv(f, delta=0.01):
    """
    Return a function which is a numerical first derivative of f
    """
    def df(x):
        a, b = f(x - delta), f(x + delta)
        return (b - a) / (2. * delta)
    return df

def newton_root(f, initial_x, tolerance=0.01, max_tries=1000):
    """
    Use Newton-Raphson method to find x such that abs(f(x)) <= tolerance
    """
    df = deriv(f)
    x  = initial_x
    for try_ in range(max_tries):
        err = f(x)
        if abs(err) <= tolerance:
            # found a solution
            return x
        else:
            # find next value for x
            x -= err / df(x)
    else:
        raise ValueError(
            "newton_root fails to converge for initial_guess = {}"
            .format(initial_x)
        )

# By inspection, path_length is a smooth upward curve (ie a U-shape)
#   on 0 .. CANAL_LEN; minimum occurs where first derivative is 0
best_dist   = newton_root(deriv(path_length), CANAL_LEN * 0.5, 0.00001)   # => 374.9999
best_length = path_length(best_dist)                  # => 1280.62484

# return results to nearest 0.1 meter
print("{:0.1f} {:0.1f}".format(best_dist, best_length))
```

---

If you play with this and think about it a while, you should realize that the shortest path is always such that the angles between leg_a and the canal and between the canal and leg_b are identical; if you think of the canal as a mirror, the shortest path is to run straight to the fire's reflection in the mirror.

This allows us to reduce the problem to a simple pair of similar triangles,

```
# TOWER_DIST / best_dist == (TOWER_DIST + FIRE_DIST) / CANAL_LEN
best_dist = TOWER_DIST * CANAL_LEN / (TOWER_DIST + FIRE_DIST)

best_length = ((TOWER_DIST + FIRE_DIST)**2 + CANAL_LEN**2) ** 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly what the error says. Python works line by line. Look above it inside your function. You never define `first_triangle_bottom_side_length". Define it in the function and the error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

The variable first_triangle_bottom_side_length might be being declared as local inside the function, to solve this you return the variable and set it outside of the function.

(Inside first triangle):

```
Return first_triangle_bottom_side_length
```

...

```
firsttrianglebottomsidelength = first_triangle(first_triangle_longest_side_length)
canal_length_left = 1000 - firsttrianglebottomsidelength
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Tim Castelijns wrote - it's a matter of scopes.
`first_triangle_bottom_side_length` is defined within the function `first_triangle` but you never returns it to your main program.

You should return it:

```
def first_triangle(first_triangle_longest_side_length):
    calculation_one = sqrt(first_triangle_longest_side_length)
    return calculation_one - sqrt(300)
[...]
[...]
while True:
    first_triangle_longest_side_length = first_triangle_longest_side_length + 0.01
    first_triangle_bottom_side_length = first_triangle(first_triangle_longest_side_length)
    canal_length_left = 1000 - first_triangle_bottom_side_length
```

Read about scopes, but more important - learn how to work with functions.

Good luck!