# finding minimum value of a variable after repeated iterations

Tags: python

```js
import math

print ('''
                               .Fire 
                               |
                               |
watch tower .                  |
            |                  |C
            |                  |
           A|                  |
            |                  |
            |________B_________|
            ====================
                   canal

             ''')

A= (int(input('please give A a value ')))
B= (int(input('please give B a value ')))
C= (int(input('please give C a value ')))

def Hypotenus1_2():
    x=(int(0))
    y=math.sqrt((int(A)*int(A))+(int(x)*int(x)))+math.sqrt((int(A)-int(x))* (int(A)-int(x))+(int(C)*int(C)))
    while x<B:
        x=x+1
        y=math.sqrt((int(A)*int(A))+(int(x)*int(x)))+math.sqrt((int(A)-int(x))*(int(A)-int(x))+(int(C)*int(C)))
        dpY=(round((y),1))
        z=math.sqrt(((int(B)-(int(x)))*(int(B)-(int(x))))+(int(C)*int(C)))
        dpZ=(round((z),1))
        print (round((dpZ+dpY),1))

Hypotenus1_2()
```

please note that i am using python 3.4.3.

ok so im trying to find the smallest possible route from the watch tower to the canal to the fire and to do so i have to find the hypotenuses and add the corresponding ones together.

However as each value of x changes so does dpZ and dpY which are added together each iteration so that the minimum route can be found. I have the values of the hypotenuses added together and can see the lowest possible route but cannot take only the min value.

So far these are my outcomes of the code.

```js
>>> 

                               .Fire 
                               |
                               |
watch tower .                  |
            |                  |C
            |                  |
           A|                  |
            |                  |
            |________B_________|
            ====================
                   canal

             
please give A a value 3
please give B a value 10
please give C a value 5
18.8
18.1
17.8
17.9
18.3
18.9
19.8
21.0
22.4
24.0
>>>
```

Comment: Why not break it down so that you get the hypotenuse of AB, and hypotenuse of BC? Then you just have to take min(hypAB + C, hypBC + A). If you import math you can even use math.hypot(x, y) to calculate your hypotenuse.

Comment: I gave a fairly elegant (IMHO) answer to this in the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887034/name-error-variable-not-defined/28903626#28888695

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to be saving your best solution at each iteration. Something along these lines:

```
import math

shortest = 0
best = 1000000
for i in range (0, B):
    hypAB = math.hypot(A, i)
    hypBC = math.hypot(i, C)
    shortest = min(hypAB + C, hypBC + A) 

    if shortest < best:
        best = shortest

print (best)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an analytic solution:

At point `x` in `[0 .. B]`, total path length `L` is `(A**2 + x**2)**0.5 + ((B - x)**2 + C**2)**0.5`

min `L` occurs when `dL/dx == 0`

```
dL/dx =  0.5 * (A**2 + x**2)**-0.5 * 2*x
       + 0.5 * ((B - x)**2 + C**2)**-0.5 * 2 * (B - x) * -1

      = x / (A**2 + x**2)**0.5 - (B - x) / ((B - x)**2 + C**2)**0.5
```

If `dL/dx == 0`,

```
x / (A**2 + x**2)**0.5 == (B - x) / ((B - x)**2 + C**2)**0.5

# square both sides
x**2 / (A**2 + x**2) == (B - x)**2 / ((B - x)**2 + C**2)

# multiply both sides by (A**2 + x**2) * ((B - x)**2 + C**2)
x**2 * ((B - x)**2 + C**2) == (B - x)**2 * (A**2 + x**2)

# expand and collect terms
(C**2 - A**2) * x**2 + (2 * A**2 * B) * x + (- A**2 * B**2) == 0
```

which is quadratic; using the quadratic formula and reducing, we get

```
x = A * B / (A + C)

L = ((A + C)**2 + B**2)**0.5
```